# How can I import NeDB as ES Mobule

Tags: javascript, nedb, esmodules

I need to import `NeDB` and I need to do this using `ES Module`, what I need from `NeDB` is `DataStore`.

When I try to import `DataStore` using the usual synthax :

```
import { DataStore } from 'nedb';
```

I have this error :

```
Named export 'Datastore' not found. The requested module 'nedb' is a CommonJS module,
which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export
```

I tried :

```
import * as nedb from 'nedb';
console.log(nedb)
// Output
// [Function: Datastore]
```

I also tried :

```
import nedb from 'nedb';
const { DataStore } = nedb;
console.log(DataStore);
// Output
// undefined
```

But how can I access `Datastore` ?

Thx,
Maxime

Comment: check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/nedb), if useful

Comment: Given your second snippet worked, it would seem to be `import * as Datastore from 'nedb';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finnaly foud the solution :

```
import DataStore from 'nedb';
// Then I can use :
new DataStore(...); // works
```

I don't know how I missed it...
Thx everyone